# AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'stream_block'

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm really new to Python3, Django & Wagtail and am trying to create an ArticlePage Model with a StreamField block used in it, and have run into problems and am getting an error:

*AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'stream_block'* error.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm obviously doing something wrong but have no idea what?

Here's the model.py code:

**articles/models.py:**

```
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from streams import blocks


from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.search import index

### Flexible Page
# Create your models here.
class ArticlePage(Page):
    subtitle = models.CharField()
    body = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField("Article date")
    team_member = models.CharField()
    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
        index.FilterField('date'),
        index.FilterField('subtitle'),
    ]

    template = "articles/article_page.html"
    #ToDo: add StreamFields
    content = StreamField(
        [
            ("team_member", blocks.TeamMembersBlock())
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    subtitle = models.CharField()
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("subtitle"),
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('related_links', label="Related links"),
        StreamFieldPanel("team_member"),
    ]

    promote_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(Page.promote_panels, "Common page configuration"),
        ImageChooserPanel('feed_image'),
    ]

    # Parent page / subpage type rules

    parent_page_types = ['articles.ArticleIndex']
    subpage_types = []

    class Meta:  # noqa
        verbose_name = "Flex Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Flex Pages"

# Create your models here.


class ArticlePageRelatedLink(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(ArticlePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                       related_name='related_links')
    name = models.CharField()
    url = models.URLField()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('url'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `StreamFieldPanel("team_member")` in your `content_panel` definition, but your StreamField is named `content`, not `team_member`. `team_member` is an entirely different field.